# How to get data from mysql db from nth row to nth row?

Tags: mysql

I am using this query but it is not working in mysql

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC) ads ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT  * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5` or `SELECT  * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT startlimit , endlimit`

Comment: from what nth row to what nth row ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ORDER BY ... LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) (lets say you want to get 5 records from 10th - 10,11,12,13,14):

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10,5
```

Although I assume you don't want to get them sorted by `id` but rather by `views` or similar criteria where `ORDER BY views DESC` would take a place (don't forget to to add index on `views` count).

Answer (score 1):

The 'TOP' does not function on MySQL. You can edit the query in the following manner to get the job done

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) ads ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 5
```